# Python display a server-side image in a html

Tags: python, html, directory, image

I have a image in the server folder. In my do_GET() function which handles the Get request I would like to send a image back. I choose to use the self.wfile.write(''). Can anyone tell me how to include the source of the image in to the img tag? Or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you writing a webserver? If not, then use a webserver for serving static assets to your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the "source" of an image in the img tag using a data URI like this:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,<your base64 encoding here>" />
```

Generate the base64 string using the base64 python standard lib:

```
import base64

with open("image.png", "rb") as image:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image.read())
```